# Refreshing Spinner after Asyctask with custom objects

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-spinner, android-adapter

I'm having a problem with refreshing my `Spinner` with a custom `Adapter`. The Custom Adapter shows the 'name' but can refere to all object data (ex. 'ID', 'age').

I use an Asynctask to import online data as JSON and store them in a SQLite Database.

In my `MainActivity`, I have a `Spinner` with the custom objects .
Now i tried a lot and failed to update the spinneradapter after updating the SQLite database with 'onPostExecute'.

I'll skip some parts of the code that are working and shouldn't impact (imports, grabbing data, database stuff, ...) to keep it clean.

Here are my CLASSES

**users.java**

```
package domain.project;

public class user{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private long id;

public User(String name, int age, long id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age= age;
        this.id = id;

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = name;
        return output;
    }
}
```

**UserDataSource.java**

```
package domain.project;

// imports skipped

public class UserDataSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public UserDataSource(Context context) {

    }
    public void open() {

       //Open database stuff

    }

    public void close() {
        //closing database stuff
    }

    public User createUser(String name, int age) {

        //writing users into SQLitedatabase stuff

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        User user = cursorToUser(cursor);
        cursor.close();

        return user;
    }

    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        //delete user from SQLitedatabase
    }

    public void refreshUser() {

        GetUsersTask getUsersTask = new GetUsersTask();
        getUsersTask.execute("Users");

    }

    public User updateUser(long id, String newName, int newAge) {
        //update User in SQLitedatabase
    }

    private User cursorToUser (Cursor cursor) {
        //getting User from SQLite Database

        User user = new User(name, age, id);

        return user;
    }


    public User[] allUsers() {
        {
        //filling Array with all Users from SQLitedatabase
        }
        return allUsers;
    }

    public class GetUsersTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {

       private String[] readJsonUser(String jsonString) {

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                String[] returnArray = new String[jArray.length()];

                //parsing JSON String to Array

                }
                return returnArray ;

            } catch (final JSONException e) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {

            if (strings.length == 0) { 
                return null;
            }

            // grabbing JSON string from web and store it in userJsonString


            return readJsonUser(userJsonString);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {

            if (strings != null) {
                //write and update SQLite database

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package domain.project;

//skipping the imports

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dataSource = new UserDataSource(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showAllListEntries();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        dataSource.close();
    }

    public void showAllListEntries() {

        final Spinner sqlUserSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_user);
        final SpinAdapter userSpinAdapter = new SpinAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, dataSource.allUsers());


        usersSpinner.setAdapter(userSpinAdapter);

        usersSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                       View view, int i, long l) {
                // Testing the selected Item
                User user = userSpinAdapter.getItem(i);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected : " + user.getId() + "<-ID   age->" + user.getAge(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public class SpinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>{

        private Context context;
        private User[] values;

        public SpinAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           User[] values) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        public int getCount(){
            return values.length;
        }

        public SQLShot getItem(int position){
            return values[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position){
            return position;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView label = new TextView(context);
            label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            label.setText(values[position].getName());
            return label;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView label = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            label.setText(values[position].getName());

            return label;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapters are not listening by default to a data set, when rhe data set change you have to pass the new data to the adapter and trigger the update.

You need inside your adapter a method to update it, updating and adapter always is a 2 step process. 1. Update your data. 2. Tell the adapter about it.

Inside your adapter create:

```
public void update(List<String> data) {
  adapterDataList.clear();
  adapterDataList.addAll(data);
  notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

You are using array, I strongly recommend you to use lists. Arrays have a fixed size which will cause you more problems.

The method notifyDatasetChanged() make the adapter knows about the change in the data list.

Since you are using SQL directly you could look at CursorAdapter.

If you want automatic data updates Realm can do that. They even have an adapter for it. Realm is an ORM I recommend an ORM over the native OpenHelper. Another good ORM is Sugar ORM not as fancy as Realm but very simple to use and good enough for your task.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter. `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. This will inform your spinner that the dataset has changed and that the US should update accordingly.